# cockroachdb data not replicating

Tags: cockroachdb, multi-master-replication

I am testing multi-master region setup in cockroach db (version v22.1.0 / Ubuntu 20.04):

```
cockroach start --insecure --store=server1 ...
cockroach start --insecure --store=server2 ...

cockroach init --insecure --host=server1

cockroach sql --insecure --host=server1:26257
```

When i insert data in node 1, and try to do a select on the same table in node 2, result in error `"ERROR: no inbound stream connection"` but select works from node 1

Additional error message from admin console for node 2:

```
failed to dial into node 2 (NODE_STATUS_LIVE): initial connection heartbeat failed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp x.x.x.x:26258: i/o timeout"
failed to dial into node 2 (NODE_STATUS_LIVE): initial connection heartbeat failed: operation "rpc heartbeat" timed out after 6s (took 6.001s): rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

can someone please advise what i am missing here ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that before you insert data, the cluster is not set up correctly. I believe you need to start a minimum of 3 nodes and check the console to make sure that all 3 are receiving heartbeats from each other.

There's more information about starting a cluster here:

- https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/start-a-local-cluster.html
- https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/secure-a-cluster.html

Make sure the --listen-addr, --http-addr, and --join arguments are correct.